Data Extract to Add All Unsubscribed Contact to Auto-Suppression List Failing
We've changed our source data for MC which has updated everyone's Subscriber Key. In order to honour unsubscribes, we want to move all our old unsubscribed subscribers to an auto-suppression list.
I've been trying to achieve this by using EITHER a data extract > file transfer > import, or via a SSJS script and neither is working and I have no idea why. Help! I'll take either solution at this point!
Below is what I'm doing. I'm clearly doing something wrong. And yes, I do have all my unsubscribes sitting nicely in a DE ready to go and be extracted.
Method 1 - Data Extract > File Import issues:
Data Extract Activity

In an automation > create Data Extract Activity
Give it a name and file naming pattern which I'm calling unsubscribes.csv. Have also tried unsubscribes.zip
Extract type = Data Extension Extract
Configuration - column delimiter is a ,
DECustomer Key = the External Key for the DE which already has all our unsubscribed users sitting in it
Has Column Headers = true. Everything else is false.

File Transfer Activity
This is what keeps failing and I don't know why!

Name the file transfer activity and select Move a File From Safehouse (is this correct?
File Naming Pattern = unsubscribes.csv (exact same as in Data Extract. Do I need to do a .zip instead?)
Destination - I've tried doing ExactTarget Enhanced FTP, tried doing one of our existing folders, tried creating a new Safehouse folder. Nothing helps here.
Run everything

No matter what I try, I get one of the following errors on the File Import activity:

File not found matching the pattern Safehouse://unsubscribes.csv
File not found matching the pattern Safehouse://unsubscribes.zip
File not found matching the pattern EnhancedSFTP://Import/unsubscribes.zip
File not found matching the pattern EnhancedSFTP://Import/unsubscribes.csv

Method 2 (also not working), the SSJS script I'm unsuccessfully using:
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load('Core', '1');

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var queryStr = '';
queryStr += 'SELECT';
queryStr += '\nEmailAddress AS [Email Address]';
queryStr += '\nDateUnsubscribed AS [Date Added]';
queryStr += '\nFROM _Subscribers';
queryStr += '\nWHERE status = \'unsubscribed\';';

var queryDef = {
  CustomerKey: 'INSERTED EXTERNAL KEY FROM SQL QUERY',
  ObjectID: 'INSERTED GUID NUMBER FROM ABOVE SQL QUERY',
  QueryText: queryStr,
  TargetType: 'DE',
  TargetUpdateType: 'addRow',
  DataExtensionTarget: {
    CustomerKey: 'INSERTED EXTERNAL KEY FOR OUR AUTO-SUPPRESSION LIST CALLED UNSUBSCRIBES',
    Name: 'Unsubscribes'
  }
};

var updateQuery = prox.updateItem('QueryDefinition', queryDef);

Write('Unsubscribed users added to \'Unsubscribes\' Data Extension: ' + Stringify(updateQuery));
</script>```





